# Haskell Repa-0.2.0.1 with vector-0.9

Tags: haskell, repa

First off, I love repa and repa-devil but most of my libraries require vector >= 0.9.  since we are on GHC 7.0.* we need to use repa-0.2.0.* but these have a hard dependency on vector >= 0.7 && < 0.8.  I was able to get repa-0.2.0.* to compile with vector-0.9 but am a bit concerned that there might be some problems lurking under the surface.

so, is it ok to relax the upper bound on the vector dependency in repa 0.2.0.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be okay if it compiles. But to prevent cabal-install from making difficulties, you should increase the version of your repa with relaxed dependencies. Pick an increase that's unlikely to become an official version number, e.g. append a `.1` to the version. When installing new packages, cabal-install takes the dependencies from the global index, so if you have a version with official dependencies `vector < 0.8`, it will think that's broken and try to reinstall it, which won't work.

Comment: good tip on the appending a version number.  will cabal choke on a version like 2.0.1.1.1 (not the 5th digit)?

Comment: @mxc Version numbers (`Data.Version`) can contain an arbitrary number of digits, cabal should cope with that, but I don't know the workings well enough to give guarantees. Try it and run `cabal install something --dry-run`, where `something` is a package depending on repa to see whether it wants to reinstall repa, if it does, just increment the last digit of the official version and hope for the best. By the way, asking the repa maintainer(s) for a new release working with `vector-0.9` would be a good thing too.

Comment: @mxc Just took a look on hackage, repa-2.2.0.1 is out and works with `vector-0.9`. So it's very unlikely that any versions with a lower number will be released.

Comment: Yeah.  Unfortunately, it also requires base 4.4 which means ghc 7.2.  Thanks though.

Comment: ghc-7.2 is great.  I'd recommend it if possible.

Comment: 7.4 is around the corner, may be better to wait for that.